# photoset repeats on blog after reblogging them

Tags: html, tumblr

After rebloging a photoset, it multiplies on my blog and looks like that (the link below) and it's quite annoying, since there are supposed to be only 2 photos. I had this problem before, but the last time I solved it by changing my theme, but I'd prefer to repair the html, if that's possible.
Thanks! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCjIs.jpg

Comment: Code? Link? Will need more information than a screenshot to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing something like this...

```
{block:Photoset}
  {block:Photos}
    {block:IndexPage}{Photoset-400}{/block:IndexPage}
    {block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
  {/block:Photos}
{/block:Photoset}
```

Just remove the `block:Photos`. To quote [the documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts):

> `{Photoset}`  Embed code for a responsive Photoset that shrinks to fit the container (max. 700-pixels wide).
>
> `{block:Photos} {/block:Photos}`  Rendered for each of the Photoset photos. Each contains the same variables as `{block:Photo}`

In this case you would be rendering the whole photoset for each photo in the photoset. I can't tell if this is what is happening without your code though.